# Days between dates calculation including bank holidays with Talend/Tableau

Tags: mysql, tableau-api, talend

I have a series of transformations and joins in a Talend OS job (from MySQL connection) which I need to perform a date calculation on.

I currently have a table of the merges etc. which I'll refer to as 'test':

(Note: date format is just for pure example - they are in mySQL format in the tables)

```
   Date    |    ReplyDate    |  NoOfDays
---------------------------------------------
  2016-01-01    2016-01-07        6
  2016-01-06    2016-01-11        5
```

...is an example of the key fields involved.  Talend's diffDate calc can and has created a 'Number of Days' field, but it doesn't allow for non-working days (which is a key calculation on the field).

I have created a separate table, called 'NWD' (non working days) which is simply...

```
   NWD
-----------
  2016-01-01
  2016-01-02
  2016-01-03
  2016-01-09
  2016-01-10
```

...etc, and lists all public/bank holidays as well as weekends.

In SQL, I know I could do:

```
SELECT COUNT(nwd) from NWD where NWD >= [Date] and NWD <= [ReplyDate]
```

..but I'm struggling to get my head around how I could generate this calculation for each row at either stages.  I'm not sure if this is something that should be handled by Talend, or a calculated field in Tableau somewho.

I'm a bit new to both, but I have tried to look at intricate joins with a tMap and tIntervalMatch in Talend, but it seems to be out of scope.  I have exported both 'tables' into a localhost MySQL so Tableau can see both datasets, but I am a bit confused as to how I would perhaps 'join' anything here.

Am I:

a) being daft and green;
b) Barking up the wrong tree with both paths, or;
c) In over my head?

Can anyone advise/guide me?   I have searched for a similar conundrum, but struggled to find anything quite in this context, although it must be a common issue?  I'm not savvy enough with Java or Talend OS at this stage to be able to create and utilise a class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi - They are stored in the mysql as per the system format %y-%m-%d etc., and are declared as a date type in all relevant areas.

Comment: You need to store public holidays, but you don't need to store weekends. So, have I understood: You want to calculate the number of working days between two days?

Comment: Indeed.

I have considered created a full calendar table, with cumulative working days sum (+1 for each work day and so on), which would mean simply a lookup for the integer value from this column for each date, then a Tableau calculated field.

That doesn't seem very efficient in my head though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To conclude this one, I performed a join in Talend with my CSV file (which contained a cumulative count of working days over a 4 year period), adding a field for every row based on the relevant date of that row.  I did this for my 'start' and 'end' dates that already existed in the data.

In Tableau, I used these lookup fields (passed over as a static 'value' which came from the CSV) to create a calculated field.

i.e. (made up example - in the UK, the 29 Aug is a Bank Holiday)

```
|  S_DATE  |  E_DATE  | S_DATE_VAL  |  E_DATE_VAL |
------------------------------------------------
| 25/08/16 | 30/08/16 |    1025     |     1027    |
```

In Tableau, simply (E_DATE_VAL) - (S_DATE_VAL) gave me my working days value.

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,start_date DATE NOT NULL
,end_date DATE NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table VALUES
(1,'2016-01-01','2016-01-07'),
(2,'2016-01-06','2016-01-11');



CREATE TABLE public_holidays (date DATE PRIMARY KEY);

INSERT INTO public_holidays VALUES ('2016-01-01');



SELECT x.*
     , 5 * (DATEDIFF(end_date, start_date) DIV 7)
       + MID('0123455501234445012333450122234501101234000123450', 7 * WEEKDAY(start_date) + WEEKDAY(end_date) + 1, 1)
       - COUNT(y.date) working_days
  FROM my_table x
  LEFT 
  JOIN public_holidays y 
    ON y.date BETWEEN x.start_date AND x.end_date 
 GROUP 
    BY x.id;
+----+------------+------------+--------------+
| id | start_date | end_date   | working_days |
+----+------------+------------+--------------+
|  1 | 2016-01-01 | 2016-01-07 |            4 |
|  2 | 2016-01-06 | 2016-01-11 |            4 |
+----+------------+------------+--------------+
```